# For Kubernetes cluster, shouldn't we have two load balancers instead of one?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

In al the tutorials about Kubernetes cluster I have read I didn't see that they mention to 2 load balancers, but only one for the ingress pods.

However, in a proper production environment, should's we have 2 different load balancers?

1. to balance between the master nodes for requests to the ApiServer.
2. to balance between the Ingress podes to control the external traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. to balance between the master nodes for requests to the ApiServer.

> For all production environments its advised to have load
> balancer for API Server.  This is the first step as part of K8S HA mode creation. More details are in [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/#create-load-balancer-for-kube-apiserver)

2. to balance between the Ingress podes to control the external traffic.

> You are correct for this also it’s definitely required to handle external traffic.  All the ingress services are created of [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) Type in their implementations.

Comment: So actually I will have 2 load balancers servers in once cluster? for example 2 instances of HaProxy? I am working on-prem, so for Ingress I will have NodePort.

Comment: It’s depends on the strategy, infra availability and factors like cost etc

Comment: for Production. lets say if I have no cost limit.

Comment: then you can have two different instances of Load Balancers